# Можно ли используя LVM извлечь физический том без потери данных?

Tags: файловая-система

Можно ли используя LVM извлечь физический том без потери данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала переносишь LV которые там лежат на другой pv

```
pvmove /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

Потом вынимаешь его из группы

```
vgreduce vg0 /dev/sda
```

Дальше можешь его отформатировать или извлечь